# How to select all the columnar values from only the first 20 unique dates (whose instance counts are not equal) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

In my dataset, each date appears several times with different hourly values for distance. The number of times each date appears is not the same. I want to select all the columns for only the first and last 20 unique dates in Pandas. Please help me to figure it out.

Here is my dataset:

```
 Distance        Date_x
0      0.089278   3/27
1      0.000275   3/27
2     21.497275   3/27
3     13.820573   3/27
4      0.000000   3/27
5      0.000000   3/27
6      0.000000   3/27
7     14.648255   3/27
8      0.389053   3/27
9      0.007374   3/27
10     0.432203   3/27
11     1.007316   3/27
12     0.678015   3/27
13     0.028617   3/27
14     0.373197   3/27
15     0.873783   3/27
16     0.043098   3/27
17     0.045681   3/27
18     1.240625   3/27
19    10.180238   3/27
20     3.267828   3/28
21     0.000774   3/28
22    35.317742   3/28
23     0.000000   3/28
24    13.820617   3/28
25    13.820617   3/28
26    20.732181   3/28
27    20.732181   3/28
28    41.461852   3/28
29     0.000000   3/28
...         ...    ...
1290   0.276866   5/30
1291   0.240057   5/30
1292   0.320576   5/30
1293   0.808575   5/30
1294   0.393489   5/30
1295   7.924056   5/31
1296   0.000177   5/31
1297   0.000000   5/31
1298   0.041471   5/31
1299   0.000000   5/31
1300   0.000000   5/31
1301   0.000000   5/31
1302   0.000000   5/31
1303   0.000000   5/31
1304   0.000000   5/31
1305   0.013843   5/31
1306   0.064182   5/31
1307   9.012817   5/31
1308  12.984884   5/31
1309   3.362251   5/31
1310   4.595614   5/31
1311   3.122168   5/31
1312  39.019543   5/31
1313  15.392655   5/31
1314  24.017332   5/31
1315  13.079625   5/31
1316  54.371674   5/31
1317  65.251377   5/31
1318  51.051755    6/1
1319  23.214170    6/1

[1320 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `unique` and `np.r_` with `isin`

```
df[df.Date_x.isin(df.Date_x.unique()[np.r_[0:20,-20:0]])]
```